# Programmatically edit iOS contacts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova, contacts

I want to edit all the phone numbers from contacts, but I want to do it programmatically. I was reading about [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) and Objective-C, but I did not find a clear way to do that. Please somebody tell me how can I do this, or someone show me a tutorial.

PD: I also need to know what the best way is to achieve that. Phonegap or Objective-C? Or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use ABAddresBook framework for editing through code,
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007082

and sample code:
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks for the help, but that example (quick contacts) displays the contact window where you can edit, i need to edit all phone numbers from the address book, without the user doing anything, just with code. thanks

Comment: u can get the contacts list and details using this framework, which allows editing programatically. go thru apple developer notes 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I read all the info you gave me, and I did not find how to do that. I can't edit a contact programmatycally :( please help

Comment: ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty)); 
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)_phoneNumber, kABPersonPhoneOtherFAXLabel, NULL); 
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil); 

        ABAddressBookRef ab = peoplePicker.addressBook;
        CFErrorRef* error = NULL;
        ABAddressBookSave(ab, error);
        CFRelease(multiPhone);

Comment: u can use ABPeoplePickerNavigationController as modal controller. It has delegate methods to retrieve, edit and other features related to addres book..